# git: copy a worktree of a remote branch that is not present at local

Tags: git, git-branch, git-clone, git-checkout, git-worktree

At work, I have a project that it has two different version with some common basic features. I make use of `git worktree` to put these versions in separate folders that I have two long-running branches beside `master` for each version and the `master` is for common features. So there are 3 folders with one repository. Also, there is a remote repository for this and the whole things are pushed there.

```
$git branch -a
*master
 version-1
 version-2
 remote/origin/master
 remote/origin/version-1
 remote/origin/version-2
```

At home PC, I have the folder of `master` and this local repository is linked to the same remote as my work repo. And when I get the list of branches it is like:

```
$git branch -a
*master
 remote/origin/master
 remote/origin/version-1
 remote/origin/version-2
```

I want to `checkout` to the `version-1` as well as copy the whole stuff of version-a to a local folder, that the folder is tracked by git as a `worktree` like at my work.
does `git clone` or `git checkout` do that or I need to do something more tricky?

Comment: by version, I mean different features for different customers, not the versioning itself!

Comment: I'm confused after reading your description because you can do the same at home with what you do at work. You can make another local branch from the remote branch at your home PC's repository, and then use `git-worktree` to check it out into another local folder.

Comment: I think you misunderstand git worktrees. They are never really "necessary", they really can just make some things faster or more space-efficient. Just start with regular `git clone` and once you have that figured out, you can work on figuring out how to replace one clone with a worktree based on the other clone.

Comment: @ElpieKay To clarify, I have a PC at work and another one at home. I work on the same project from both places.  As you suggest, if I make another local branch from the remote branch at my home, doesn't it add another unnecessary branch? I want to have my old 3 branches that I mentioned.

Comment: @Mort The `worktree` helped me a lot, with separating folders and my IDE won't confused. again, I have my 3 separate folders at work PC, but just 1 folder for the master at my home PC (because I left working at home for a while before I add these 1 and 2 version things), now I get back to work at home and need to update my working folders, but I want it to be tracked by remote git branch.

Comment: I think I found the solution. first `git checkout version-1` then it added to my local branches automatically. then `git worktree add ../version-1 version-1` which creates me a folder beside the master folder and copy the file in there. now when I switch to each folder using `cd ../version-1` or `cd ../master` it automatically checks out for me. thanks guys for guide me. I love git!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I use this to have the same work-trees like at my work, at my home.

```
$ git worktree add --checkout ../version-1 version-1
$ git worktree add --checkout ../version-2 version-2
```

It checkout my long-running branches in different folders(work-trees).